# Is it correct to use the Handler together with Async Task within the same class?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, android-handler

As you know, there is [a good downloadable sample called "Location Aware" in the Android Development Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html).

I have a question about the Handler written in this code. Is it correct to use the Handler together with Async Task within the same class? Is this code written correctly according to the Android standard ? (BTW, this project works fine if some error fixed.)

Reference for the Async Task : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    .....
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mGeocoderAvailable;
    ...

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mUseFine = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_FINE);
            mUseBoth = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_BOTH);
        } else {
            mUseFine = false;
            mUseBoth = false;
        }
        mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlng);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);

        ..............

        // Handler for updating text fields on the UI like the lat/long and address.
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
                        mAddress.setText((String) msg.obj);
                        break;
                    case UPDATE_LATLNG:
                        mLatLng.setText((String) msg.obj);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        // Get a reference to the LocationManager object.
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    ...............
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        LocationManager locationManager =
                (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        ........

    private void setup() {
        Location gpsLocation = null;
        Location networkLocation = null;
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        mLatLng.setText(R.string.unknown);
        mAddress.setText(R.string.unknown);

        if (mUseFine) {
            mFineProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);
            mBothProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);

            gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);

            if (gpsLocation != null) updateUILocation(gpsLocation);
        } else if (mUseBoth) {

            mFineProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_inactive);
            mBothProviderButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);

            gpsLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_gps);
            networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, R.string.not_support_network);

            ........

    private void doReverseGeocoding(Location location) {
        // Since the geocoding API is synchronous and may take a while.  You don't want to lock
        // up the UI thread.  Invoking reverse geocoding in an AsyncTask.
        (new ReverseGeocodingTask(this)).execute(new Location[] {location});
    }

    private void updateUILocation(Location location) {
        // We're sending the update to a handler which then updates the UI with the new
        // location.
        Message.obtain(mHandler,
                UPDATE_LATLNG,
                location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude()).sendToTarget();

        // Bypass reverse-geocoding only if the Geocoder service is available on the device.
        if (mGeocoderAvailable) doReverseGeocoding(location);
    }

    private final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // A new location update is received.  Do something useful with it.  Update the UI with
            // the location update.
            updateUILocation(location);
        }

        .........


    // AsyncTask encapsulating the reverse-geocoding API.  Since the geocoder API is blocked,
    // we do not want to invoke it from the UI thread.
    private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, Void> {
        Context mContext;

        public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Location... params) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

            Location loc = params[0];
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Update address field with the exception.
                Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, e.toString()).sendToTarget();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                // Format the first line of address (if available), city, and country name.
                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getLocality(),
                        address.getCountryName());
                // Update address field on UI.
                Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, addressText).sendToTarget();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...............
```

Comment: I think this provided sample code is wrong. what do you think ? I would like to listen the skillful and experienced expert's opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. we can use it.  There is no wrong in that. If you want you can also separate them in two classes.

Comment: yes, it works fine for my test app. Sometimes the yellow lint message in the Handler just occurred. But I think that the handler is not required in this AsyncTask mode. Because memory leaks occurr in this code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you use an anonymous inner class in java which obtains a reference to the outer object instance. (your handler in this case)

Make the inner class static and pass in the PARENT_CLASS as a constructor parameter and use WeakReference to store the reference.

This prevents a circular dependency chain within the Garbage Collector.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

WeakReference still allows you to easily 'point to' an object, but when that object has no other (Strong) references... it will be garbage collected. (This is the desired outcome) (and is particularly important in Android with limited RAM)

EDIT: This is a very subtle memory leak that is hard to catch unless you are specifically looking for it. The reason for it is that Java adds an implicit reference to all non-static inner classes (I'm not 100% sure about lambda notations, but I think not... but I need to look into that...) that points to the instance object that created the inner class instance... This leads to a cycle in the GC's tracking of references... and creates a memory leak of both objects being kept in memory when they aren't needed. (Mind you this is more important when you handling your own threading... but still a good practice to get into)